# Seurat VlnPlot presenting expression of multiple genes in a single cluster

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat, ggplot2

Seurat VlnPlots are most commonly used to visualize differences in any given gene expression across multiple clusters or cell types. For example:

```
VlnPlot(object = MouseCellAtlas, idents = c("T cell","Neutrophil","Erythroblast","Monocyte","Macrophage"), features = 'Fzd9')
```

[image: Seurat VlnPlot for a single gene in multiple cluster idents]

But suppose I want to view the expression of several genes in just `idents = "T cell"`. I can do this to generate three separate plots:

```
VlnPlot(object = mca, idents = 'T cell', features = c('Fzd9','Ctnnb1','Apc'), combine = TRUE, ncol = 3)
```

[image: Seurat plot for multiple genes in a single cluster ident]

But ideally I'd like this second plot to look just like the first plot, except with only a single tissue on the legend ("T cell") and multiple genes in the various colored violins. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any simple way to combine these violins into a single plot area.

This doesn't do what I need:

```
VlnPlot(object = mca, idents = 'T cell', features = c('Fzd9','Ctnnb1','Apc'), combine = TRUE, ncol = 3)
```

Is there built-in functionality in Seurat for generating a VlnPlot for multiple genes in a single tissue in a single plot? Or can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so one workaround it to have your data in "long format" and then use the column that holds the "gene names" as the `x` variable while plotting.

You can use `FetchData()` to extract data from a `Seurat` object. `VlnPlot`'s default is the `data` slot (of the active assay if using Seurat v3 I suppose). And you can specify which cells and genes to retrieve.

```
selected_cells <- names(panc8$celltype[panc8$celltype == "gamma"])
data <- FetchData(panc8,
                    vars = c('FZD9','CTNNB1','APC'),
                    cells = selected_cells ,
                    slot = "data")
> head(data)
           FZD9   CTNNB1      APC
D101_5        0 0.000000 0.000000
D101_43       0 2.007853 1.001958
D101_93       0 0.000000 0.000000
```

`Melt()` would transform your data into "long format". By not specifying any arguments, we push for all of the info in the three variables to be gathered in two columns:

```
long_data <- melt(data)
No id variables; using all as measure variables
> head(long_data)
  variable value
1     FZD9     0
2     FZD9     0
3     FZD9     0

> tail(long_data)
     variable value
1870      APC     0
1871      APC     0
1872      APC     0
```

`ggplot2` is used to add "violin" and "jitter" layers. You can customize the output to look (exactly) like the `VlnPlot()` output.

```
ggplot(long_data,
       aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_jitter(size = 0.1)
```

[image]

And here is the same graph generated by `VlnPlot()`:

[image]

There are no "violins" as the counts are almost entirely zeros. And see how different the ranges are in the y axes of the `VlnPlot`. So the "tweak" I have presented here would only work for genes that are expressed at similar levels / similar ranges.

Comment: thanks, this works well! The general approach will be useful moving forward with a number of other analyses as well. Thanks!